# jQuery jVectorMap Dynamic Map Loading

Tags: jquery, ajax, jvectormap

Using jVectorMap I have a map of the United States whereupon you click a state and then a popup comes up for a map of that individual state.

The popup is loaded via AJAX (not using jQuery) and the following occurs:

1. A script is executed for the map. It is a really long file, but is all part of the following:

   $.fn.vectorMap('addMap',....
2. The scripts for the rest of the popup are located further down.

   var map = new jvm.WorldMap({
       container: $('.stateMap'),
       map: 'indiana',
       backgroundColor:'none',
       zoomOnScroll:false,
       series: {
           regions: [{
               attribute: 'fill',
               normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
           }]
       }
   });
3. This is executed and gives the following error:

   Error: Attempt to use map which was not loaded: indiana

I can load all of the maps before any of the AJAX calls occur, but I would prefer not to load 51 maps at once.

Answer (score 0):

I in the end bypassed the need to use vectorMap function. And although I would love to find out how to get that to actually work, I am nonetheless satisfied with what I ended up with.

I decided to add the 'addMap' function to the jvm object. At the beginning it looks like the following:

```
var jvm={addMap:function(n,m){jvm.WorldMap.maps[n]=m},//...
```

Because I do not know enough of the intricacies of jVectorMap this may be too much of a hack ignoring many things, but it does work for the SVG maps that I am loading. You can use it as follows:

```
jvm.addMap(mapName,{mapData});
```